# how to flutterfire web site (document)?

Tags: firebase, flutter

sorry i'dont no english (i'm use google translation)

a month ago

i'm use site page
[image]

but now go to page

[image]

The site has changed.
I want flutter Firebase example code.
but, it is not found on the changed site.

plase after web site and flutter firebase example code document.

Comment: Are these the sites?: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android and https://pub.dev/packages/flutterfire_ui, or https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/codelab Or, maybe https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#dart_1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: [Federated identity and social auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/federated-auth)

Edited:

Here's the screenshot from the page: left side all auth methods, right side all contents in the page. In the form of a menu list, both. In the pages you can find all the code examples.
Are they other examples you need that were on the previous version?

[image]

Comment: Thank you.

How do I look at the other example codes?

Where can I see the menu items?

Comment: Can you please specify what other example codes do you need and what do you mean with menu items?

Comment: Like the old version

I want links to various examples in the form of a menu list on the left side of the website.

Comment: OMG //
When I chose the language in Korean, the flutter menu didn't come out

The menu is coming out because I chose the language in English

Thank you.